# How to select all checkboxes with Selenium-WebDriver with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selectcheckboxmenu

I would like to select all checkboxes in a table, using javascript language in Selenium webdriver. I'm new to Selenium and I just can't find the right solution, so I would be grateful for any help.

PS. I have 10 rows in my table.

The html:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td class="dt-row="0" dt-column="0"> 
     <span class="grid-select-row-span">        
       <label class="check">           
          <input type="checkbox" class="grid-select-row">
          <i></i>       
        </label>   
   </span>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
   <td data-dt-row="1" data-dt-column="0">
      <span class="grid-select-row-span">       
         <label class="check">         
            <input type="checkbox" class="grid-select-row">
               <i></i>     
         </label>   
      </span>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

My selenium code:

```
driver.findElements(By.css("grid-select-row")).then(function (elements) { 
     elements.forEach(function(element) {
          console.log(elements.length);
         if(!element.Selected)
         {
             driver.actions() .
             mouseDown(element) .
             click(element);

            // element.click();
         }
     });              
    });
```

Comment: I think the function for select state is isSelected() in webdriverio. CHeck this out - http://webdriver.io/api/state/isSelected.html and for clicking the checkbox - http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Andersson no, I don't get any error, neither nothing will happen :/

Comment: @Grasshopper I've already tried this: 
 if(!element.isSelected())
         {
            element.click();
         } 
but I got the same result, I didn't get any errors, neither nothing happen :/

Comment: @JanP I am not a Javascript expert but the sample code in the documentation and what you are using are different. They are passing the selector into the isSelected() method and then using promise as '.then' to work on it further.

Comment: @Grasshopper Do you mean the sample code in webdriver.io (upper documentation)? I'm using selenium-webdriver not webdriverio..

Answer (score 0):

To point to element with some `class` you should use form `.className`, but not just `className`, so try this `CSS` selector instead:

```
input.grid-select-row
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still won't check the checkboxes.

Comment: Could you try `document.querySelector("input.grid-select-row").click();` from browser console? If it works, you should check your code syntax

Comment: I tried and it selected just the first checkbox. I also tried jQuery in browser console: $("input.grid-select-row").prop("checked", true); and it worked fine as I wanted. But I can't figured it out how to do it in selenium.

Comment: Yes, it should check just first one- I just wanted to check correctness of locator. In `selenium` it works in exactly the same way as in your `jQuery`: check current state and make click if element unchecked with appropriate methods `isChecked()` and `click()`

Comment: so this:
var enElement=driver.findElement(By.css("input.grid-select-row"));
     if(enElement.isSelected())     {
        console.log("Element je selectan"); }
    else {
        enElement.click(); } 

should work?

Comment: I'm not sure about syntax as I have a little expirience with `JS`. If `enElement.isSelected()` not works, try `enElement.isChecked()`

Comment: .isChecked() is not a function, so I tried .isChecked and got an error: ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Comment: Seems that you should use `isDisplayed()` method in loop to wait until target checkbox to be visible as there is no such possibilities in `JS` as in other languages to use explicit wait